# XPath in an Element

Tags: xslt, xpath

Is it correct that it is possible to use XPath only on the document node?

I have an XSLT where I want to do the following:

```
<xsl:variable name="parameters" select="doc('document.xml')//element"/>
<xsl:variable name="file" select="$parameters/file/@file"/>
```

but it selects nothing.

Comment: You should really show us a representative XML input sample if you want anyone to help explain why the XPath expressions selected nothing.

Comment: No, it is not correct.

Comment: Your XPath expressions are perfectly valid per se; if they don't select anything, then it's because the source document doesn't contain elements/attributes with matching names. On StackOverflow, the most common reason for path expressions not selecting anything is that people haven't taken namespaces into account.

Comment: Is there an element named `element` in document.xml? If not, then most probably you want: `doc('document.xml')//*`